# Laravel with shared sessions and multiple applications

Tags: laravel

I have a requirement to allow users to login using a central place and that should ctreate sessions to be used across multiple applications.

At the moment we have two backend applications running with Laravel, the database is shared between the applications. Then we have a few frontend apps that communicate with the backend ones via API calls.

The frontend apps use Laravel Sanctum for the communication. That's quite easy since we use always the same base domain. So it's `backend1.ourdomain.com`, `backend2.ourdomain.com`, `frontend1.ourdomain.com`, `frontend2.ourdomain.com`, `frontend3.ourdomain.com`.

At the moment we store the sessions using Redis.
The idea is to migrate sessions to the database and then allow the applications to use that share session. We would also create a central point for the login, logout and account management. Something like `my-account.ourdomain.com`.

So, the flow would be:

1. User visits `backend1.ourdomain.com`
2. No session, so the user is redirected to `my-account.ourdomain.com`
3. User enter their credentials and a cookie is created
4. User is redirected back to `backend1.ourdomain.com`
5. User then acesss `backend2.ourdomain.com`
6. Since there's a cookie session already created the user doesn't have to authenticate again
7. User access `frontend1.ourdomain.com`
8. Access is also granted since we use Laravel Sanctum with cookie session auth.

What I imagine is the right solution is to:

- `APP_KEY` same on both backends
- `SESSION_CONNECTION` same on both backends
- `SESSION_STORE` same on both backends
- `SESSION_COOKIE` same on both backends
- `SESSION_DOMAIN` same on both backends. eg.: `.ourdomain.com`

Does it makes sense?

I tried the solution above but got some weird behavior on my local environment when I check the "keep me logged in" checkbox from the login form.
When I do that I keep getting a `419 page expired` error.
If I don't check the checkbox it seems to work but that's not ideal.